# Get result of form submission

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have the following form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.gotEmail}>
  <div className="form-group">
    <FormControl type="text" className="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" type="submit">Send</Button>
</form>
```

When submitted, I would like to get the field written by the user here:

```
<FormControl type="text" className="form-control"/>
```

I tried getting it like this:

```
gotEmail: function(email) {
    console.log("Email: ", JSON.stringify(email))
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
EmailForm.jsx:9 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

When I try to print `email` in the console I am getting this:

```
(program):132 Uncaught illegal access
```

How can I get the user's input?

Comment: Are you using any js framework?

Comment: (S)He's using React.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript you would probably do the following :

> HTML:

```
<form action="getInput()">
<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control"/>
</form>
```

> JS:

```
function getInput(){
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
alert(email);
}
```

aaaaaaa

Comment: Where do you import `getViewById` from?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to access an HTML element of your component in React is:

```
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'

[...] // all your other script stuff here

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.gotEmail}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <FormControl ref="email" type="text" className="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" type="submit">Send</Button>
    </form>
  )
}

gotEmail() {
  console.log(findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value)
}
```